# Matching text field's value with array contents in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

I have some arrays whose contents are picked from db.I want to match up  the text i have entered in 'searchTextField' with those array's contents which is taken from DB.

**For example:** my array contains, `myArray={'bat man','bat and ball','ball'};`
if i have entered 'bat' in 'searchTextField'; it must show index of matching text in array(in this case index 0 and 1).

How can i achieve this..
Waiting for your help..

Comment: Try something with tableSearch: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"bat man",@"bat and ball",@"ball", nil];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] 'bat'"];
NSArray *result = [tempArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

`result` array will be containing the filtered objects, from there you can get the index as:

> [tempArray indexOfObject:/*the object from result array, one by one*/]

`contains[c]` means search will be case insensitive. For more on predicates: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html

**EDIT**

set the textField's delegate as self. Before that go to YourFile.h, there add `UITextFieldDelegate`. now in `textFieldShouldReturn` do this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"bat man",@"bat and ball",@"ball", nil];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@",textField.text];
    NSArray *result = [tempArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    return YES;
}
```